# vlc android streaming by ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, android, vlc

I have tried to play video from my PC to android app but the android app can not find the PC vlc.

When i run the vlc on my PC i have this error:

```
 vlc
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
[00005577d41cb470] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
> [00005577d41d57b0] [http] lua interface: Lua HTTP interface
[00005577d41d57b0] [http] main interface error: socket bind error: Address already in use
[00005577d40ee570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00005577d41e3a20] [telnet] lua interface: Listening on host "telnet://:1234".
[00005577d40f24e0] main playlist: playlist is empty
[00007fa24c7a4890] [http] lua interface: Lua HTTP interface
[00007fa24c7a4890] [http] lua interface error: Error loading script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/intf/http.luac: lua/intf/http.lua:244: Failed to create HTTPd file.
```

And  in this time i have this port open:

```
so@so-notebook:~$  netstat -lp |grep vlc
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1234            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2083/vlc            
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http-alt           [::]:*                  LISTEN      2083/vlc            
tcp6       0      0 [::]:1234               [::]:*                  LISTEN      2083/vlc
```

The vlc setting is :

[image]

and the **$HOME/.config/vlc/vlcrc** file is like [this](https://0bin.net/paste/MHHTVXWaGvmO4Od3#88c563PLn7ASHnII05F1QIZdrCdc6IzMLfbnLxV2wji).

Also at app port is settled on **8080**, pass is **1234** and  the IP is settled by **ifconfig** output result in PC.

So what do you thin i mus to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Your output shows: `[00005577d41d57b0] [http] main interface error: socket bind error: Address already in use`

Comment: Which ip and port is used?!